# How to define or format date when show column in grid with Vuetify.js

Tags: vuetify.js

How to define or format date when show column in grid with Vuetify.js

I tried with *cellFilter* same Angular js but can not.
Can anyone help me :

- Displays the date field returned from database format "dd-MM-yyyy"
- With other formats

Thanks

```
    vm = new Vue({
    el: '#demo-table',
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            selected: [],
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Hành động',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: false,
                    width: 250
                },
                {
                    text: 'Tên',
                    align: 'left',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'STUDENTNAME',
                    width : 250
                },
                {
                    text: 'Địa chỉ',
                    align: 'center',
                    value: 'ADDRESS',
                    width: 250
                },
                {
                    text: 'Ngày sinh',
                    align: 'center',
                    value: 'BIRTHDAY',
                    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
                    width: 250
                },
                {
                    text: 'Chiều cao',
                    align: 'center',
                    value: 'HEIGHT',
                    width: 250
                }
            ],
            desserts: vd_StudentInfo
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you speak clear ?

Comment: Can you post a CodePen ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vng-hng-vnh/pen/ejJLdg?editors=1010

Comment: example with column Birth day, to want to format "dd/mm/yyyy", data returned from db oracle

Answer (score 0):

For resolve your problem, you can do this.

Inside of your headers, don´t use the property "format" beacause it don´t exists. Instead use the property: value, and configure it.

I take your code as example:

```
*vm = new Vue({
el: '#demo-table',
data() {
    return {
        search: '',
        selected: [],
        headers: [
            {
                text: 'Hành động',
                align: 'center',
                sortable: false,
                width: 250
            },
            {
                text: 'Ngày sinh',
                align: 'center',
                value: 'BIRTHDAY' | formatDate('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                width: 250
            },
```

---

The hack of it, is use of:

```
yourProperty | formatDate('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

---

You could will find more information about it in: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props

---

Good look!